# Visual studio error unable to start debigging xamarin.forms ios project

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I code with visual studio 2015 update 3 and Xamarin.Forms.When I try to debug my iOS project I get an error immediately.

[image: The error]

I always select debug - iphone simulator and set the iOS project to startup project.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are connected to a Mac Device. When you're connected, the debug for iOS is automatically checked.

If you want to manually check the option, go to menu

```
Build -> Configuration Manager
```

and make sure the Build is check for iOS

If still doesn't work, I would suggest, update your visual studio or download the latest Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: I have connected to Mac device and V.S. got all simulators. But the problem still exist.

Comment: Yes, the build is check for iOS. 
Also when I rebuild my solution, I got 3 success.

Comment: I added tips in my answer

Comment: In new project I have no issue. Everything works well. Also when I go to project properties, I can't see iOS build and other properties but just in this project.